# Quick search for line in sorted 5 GB file

Tags: c#, .net, search, .net-4.6

I have to determine if a given line (as string) exists in a sorted text file. The data on this file changes every day and, on average, there are 152 million records and the file weighs approximately 5GB. The file is alphabetically ordered and records are separated by a new line.

**Example**: search hello

**File:**
apple
banana
catsup
dog
hello

I don't need to search the entire file. Once I found an exact name, it can return either a string or int. Just to prove its existence.

I have tried the following:

```
using (var sr = new StreamReader(txtFile))
{
   string line;
   while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
   {
       if (line == searchedWord)
           return true;
   }
   return false;
}
```

```
int result = File.ReadLines(txtFile).Count(line => line.Equals(searchedWord));
if (result > 0)
   return true;
return false;
```

My question is: Is there a better solution to find the line?

Comment: That's a status update, what is your question?

Comment: I'd have used Any, not Count

Comment: @CaiusJard sorry for that. please see my edited answer.

Comment: Divide and conqure strategy may get you fast results. run each section in a pool of threads and I guess itd be fine

Comment: Are the lines in the file “ordered” in any way? The sample looks sorted.

Comment: @JohnG yes it is alphabetically sorted.

Comment: @Rika I tried. whenever I analyzed each string to check, it took 10-12 seconds each that's why I'm having a trouble

Comment: If it's an ordered list, you have a huge advantage for speeding things up.

Comment: If its sorted, could you not check the first character, and if the first character is greater than the searched for first character, you could quit looking?

Comment: @Andy could you please expound those advantages?

Comment: You can use readblock method in stream read and run a parallel task with cancellation token to find the match from the block, If any 1 of ur thread finds match,you need to cancel other threads using the cancellation. This may speed up your process

Comment: Does this file change? if not just use a db, it can index and would do this in milliseconds

Comment: @Purushothaman okay thank you for that idea. maybe I can try that.

Comment: If you cant use a db, you could look at indexing the file yourself if it doesnt change often. if that is still not possible, i would look at creating a FileSream first and using a larger buffer size it may give you a speed boost.

Comment: @MichaelRandall yes it changes everyday

Comment: Note that reading a file in threads/tasks generally wont help much, if you have the appropriate buffer size, and your FileSream option is set to sequential .

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. I can try some of your suggestions. I will update this thread once I found the solution. Thank you again.

Comment: I couldn't add answer, but you should read about binary search, and adapt to your case. I suggest to use streams with seek and when you will have small set like few KB, read it into table and use integrated in array class binary search to determine if there is this string or not.

Answer (score 3):

I have tested this code:

```
private static bool ReadLineByLine(string path, string needle)
{
    using (var sr = new StreamReader(path))
    {
        string line;
        while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            if (line == needle)
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

And it find a string that's at the end of a 5 GB file in 12 seconds. If your program takes all day to do this, I'd suggest not reading from a spinning disk of rust on a 486, but buying a $50 SSD and decent CPU and processing the file on that hardware.

You need to analyze where the slowness is coming from, and you need to show some actual numbers. Are you reading from a network share, and how long does your program take?

You can go perform some tricks to read the file in chunks of an ideal size for your filesystem, parallelize the processing of those chunks (and consider that one chunk may contain the start of the needle, and the next chunk the remainder) and so on, but realise that a lot of work went into making the framework's disk access as efficient as it can be.

Don't outsmart the framework, run your code on decent hardware.

Comment: If I may ask, would it not depend on how many “lines” are in the file since it is read line by line as opposed to strictly the size? I would think a 5GB file with 500,000 lines would be significantly less work as opposed to a 5GB file with 152 million lines would it not?

Comment: "*I'd suggest not reading from a spinning disk of rust on a 486*" - awww yeah +1

Comment: @JohnG StreamReader buffers internally, and for reasonably small lines, think log files, this doesn't matter much. It's a different story of course when the file contains one 5 GB long "line" (i.e. no newline characters in the file), that'll probably throw an OutOfMemoryException somewhere along the line. Anyhow I generated a file with 50 character lines, not including the newline.

Comment: @CodeCaster thank you for your answer. right now, I'm running it on an SSD personal computer. for testing purposes.

Comment: @gail so, what is your question? How long does your code take, and is that a problem?